# Implementing BandRNN with pytorch and tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

So I am trying to figure out how to train my matrix in a way that I will get a BandRNN.

BandRnn is a diagonalRNN model with a different number of connections per neuron.
For example:
[image]
C is the number of connections per neuron.

I found out that there is a way to turn off some of the gradients in a for loop, in a way that prevents them from being trained as follows:

```
for p in model.input.parameters():
         p.requires_grad = False
```

But I can't find a proper way to do so, in a way that will make my matrix become a BandRNN.

Hopefully, someone will be able to help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can only activate/deactivate `requires_grad` on a tensor, and not on distinct components of that tensor. Instead what you could do is zero out the values outside the band.

First create a mask for the band, you could use [`torch.ones`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ones.html) with [`torch.diagflat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.diagflat.html):

```
>>> torch.diagflat(torch.ones(5), offset=1)
```

By setting the right dimension for `torch.ones` as well as the right offset you can generate offset diagonal matrices with consistent shapes.

```
>>> N = 10; i = -1
>>> torch.diagflat(torch.ones(N-abs(i)), offset=i)
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])

>>> N = 10; i = 0
>>> torch.diagflat(torch.ones(N-abs(i)), offset=i)
tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])

>>> N = 10; i = 1
>>> torch.diagflat(torch.ones(N-abs(i)), offset=i)
tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

You get the point, summing these matrices element-wise allows use to get a mask:

```
>>> N = 10; b = 3
>>> mask = sum(torch.diagflat(torch.ones(N-abs(i)), i) for i in range(-b//2,b//2+1))

>>> mask
tensor([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Then you can zero out the values outside the band on your [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html):

```
>>> m = nn.Linear(N, N)
>>> m.weight.data = m.weight * mask

>>> m.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.3321, -0.3377, -0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000],
        [-0.4197,  0.1729,  0.2101,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.3467,  0.2857, -0.3919, -0.0659,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000, -0.4060,  0.0908,  0.0729, -0.1318],
        [ 0.0000, -0.0000, -0.4449, -0.0029, -0.1498]], requires_grad=True)
```

Note, you might need to perform this on each forward pass as the parameters outside the band might get updated to non-zero values during the training. Of course, you can initialize `mask` once and keep it in memory.

It would be more convenient to wrap everything into a custom `nn.Module`.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer!
Indeed, it looks like it will work.
But is there any change to "save" the time of those calculations in the train, instead of resetting them to zero?
I read somewhere about "freeze neuron", but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"But is there any change to "save" the time of those calculations in the train"* exactly? I'm affraid you cannot manipulate your layers as *neurons*, the smallest component would be the underlying matrix itself.

Comment: Overall, the paper I implementing is about "Rethinking full connectivity in recurrent neural networks", in which bandRNN are implemented, and the calculation time decreased significantly (compared to the traditional implementations). What I meant to ask is - will your procedure decrease calculation time (since we don't affect the loss calculation time).